# DDoS attack mitigation on Azure infrastructure

Tags: azure

I have a Django based web application hosted on Azure provisioned virtual machines (Ubuntu OS). My application recently experienced a DDoS attack and we were helpless against it.

The problem is that once traffic hits the server - even if it's blocked at a firewall or throttled in my webserver - the traffic is already consuming my network bandwidth. I can do nothing about it. This needs to be blocked "upstream", in the routing gear servicing my server.

Is there any DDoS protection Azure can offer me? Or at the very least, make recommendations as to how I might deploy my application so that it's more resistant to these attacks? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current, Azure provides DDOS protection at the network level, but not at the application level.  So, if you are receiving a bunch of ACK requests, for example, this should be blocked by the platform itself.

For app level DDOS protection, you need to consider an upstream provider such as Incapsula or Silverline.  Integrating them is quite easy.  See https://www.incapsula.com/blog/how-to-add-incapsula-to-your-microsoft-azure-instance.html for an example.

Essentially, you will setup Incapsula and configure it with the DNS label of the web app (something.azurewebsites.net).  Your DNS (www.domain.com) will then point to the incapsula service and they will handle the rest.

Please note that separating the DDOS from the service still allows for an attack against the service itself (ie: if someone hits something.azurewebsites.net then Incapsula will not protect this traffic).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Being new to this, I need some clarification on ACK requests. I'm assuming you're referring to what is known as a SYN-ACK flood? How do I specifically go through various logs to identify whether this was the type of DDoS attack we suffered?

Comment: Most of those "incomplete tcp handshake" type of ddos attacks are not logged by the OS by default.  I guess my question back to you would be how do you know you experienced a ddos attack?

Comment: Azure now has WAF part of Application Gateway , which can be used to front-end web traffic and protects at application level not only DoS attacks but also OWASP top 10 (like XSS, CSRF and SQL Injection)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-application-firewall-overview

Comment: @CtrlDot: sudden spike in requests per second (around 10X more than the highest I've experienced) within a couple of seconds, escalated network I/O followed by messages from an anonymous source claiming responsibility.

Comment: If you were seeing the http requests then it was an app level attack.  Incapsula would be the way to go

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

First: Azure allows for IP-whitelisting (or blacklisting), so you can add malicious IP addresses to your block-list on incoming traffic (port 80/443 for instance). And you can modify IP addresses / ranges programmatically. This should prevent traffic from hitting your web app. *Note: This is specific to Azure Virtual Machines, which you're using.*

Second: Azure provides the Azure Security Center, which is designed to detect such things as DoS attacks, intrusion attacks, etc. Not that it solves your problem, but it can be used for alerting you to issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using incapsula will be the right answer for you , since incapsula hides your origin ip and mitigate the attack before it even reached Azure.

in addition it provides CDN and cache which helped us save on bandwidth costs on AWS and make our application work faster.